# removing all word occurence in a bash variable

Tags: bash, find-occurrences

i have a variable like this: (each word in a new line)

```
> echo $LIST
toto
toto2
titi
rererer
dfs
sdfsdf
titi
titi
```

I try to remove all occurences of "titi" to obtain that:

```
> echo $LIST
toto
toto2
rererer
dfs
sdfsdf
```

i tried with **LIST=$(echo ${LIST//titi/})** and it remove it but it also delete new line and give this result:

```
> echo $LIST
toto toto2 rererer dfs sdfsdf
```

My question is how to remove all occurences keeping each word in a line ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: subshell and echo are redundant

Comment: can you try:      echo  "$list"|grep -v titi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `"${LIST//titi/}"`, otherwise whitespace will be collapsed:

```
$ LIST='toto
> toto2
> titi
> rererer
> dfs
> sdfsdf
> titi
> titi'
$ echo "${LIST//titi/}"
toto
toto2

rererer
dfs
sdfsdf
```

But you can also just assign directly:

```
LIST=${LIST//titi/}
echo "$LIST" # quotes are important here!
```